# Создание нового листа в файле Excel по достижению определенного количества

Tags: c#, epplus

Есть список `List<AddTabsClass> propList` который я хочу заполнять в таблицу Excel. Я хочу по достижению допустим строки 1000 создать новый лист и в него продолжить заполнять данные из списка.
Я пытаюсь так:

```
            using (ExcelPackage excelPackage = new ExcelPackage())
        {

            int i = 2;
            for (int j = 1; j < 10; j++)
            {
                excelPackage.Workbook.Properties.Subject = "Export property to Excel";
                ExcelWorksheet workSheet = excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("PROP" + j.ToString());
                workSheet.Cells["A1"].Value = "FILE NAME";
                workSheet.Cells["B1"].Value = "TAB NAME";
                workSheet.Cells["C1"].Value = "PROPERTY NAME";
                workSheet.Cells["D1"].Value = "PROPERTY VALUE";
                foreach (var val in propList)
                {
                    workSheet.Cells[i, 1].Value = val.FileName;
                    workSheet.Cells[i, 2].Value = val.TabName;
                    workSheet.Cells[i, 3].Value = val.PropName;
                    workSheet.Cells[i, 4].Value = val.PropValue;
                    i++;
                    if (i == 1000)
                    {
                        i = 1000;
                        break;
                    }
                    if (i == 2000)
                    {
                        i = 2000;
                        break;
                    }

                }

            }
            FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(path + "TEST.xlsx");
            try
            {
                excelPackage.SaveAs(fi);

            }
            catch { }

            //}



            //foreach (AddTabsClass s in propList)
            //{
            //    workSheet.Cells[i, 1].Value = s.FileName;
            //    workSheet.Cells[i, 2].Value = s.TabName;
            //    workSheet.Cells[i, 3].Value = s.PropName;
            //    workSheet.Cells[i, 4].Value = s.PropValue;
            //    i++;
            //}

        }
```

Но никак не могу догнать, как сделать правильно.
Подскажите пожалуйста

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил с помощью данного метода:

```
        public static List<List<T>> Split<T>(IList<T> source)
    {
        return source
            .Select((x, i) => new { Index = i, Value = x })
            .GroupBy(x => x.Index / 1000)
            .Select(x => x.Select(v => v.Value).ToList())
            .ToList();
    }
```